# Generating a unified report of all changes prior to Subversion commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, ankhsvn

I would like to know whether there is a tool that can work with Subversion (which I use via Tortoise and Ankh) to generate a pre-commit report of all of my changes (across all files).

This is so that I can easily visually inspect my changes for accuracy prior to committing, without having to perform individual 'diffs' on each file.

In response to @alroc's question, what I wish for is roughly:

```
FILENAME1.CPP
>>> Line 1234 Was
    int i = 3;
>>>> Line 1234 Now
    int j = 3;

>>>> Line 2345 Was
    string s = "Hello";
>>>> Line 2345 Now
    string s = "Goodbye";


FILENAME2.CPP
>>>> Line 100 Was
    for (int i = 1 to 10)
    {
        DoSomething (i);
    }
>>>> Line 100 Now
    for (int i = 1 to 12)
    {
        DoSomethingElse (i);
    }
```

Comment: What do you envision this "report" looking like? `svn st` will tell you what files have changed, `svn diff` (which I'm pretty sure can be run against the whole working copy) will tell you what in those files has changed.

Comment: I seem to remember that Tortoise did a Unified diff at some point, which just showed you the 'before' and 'after' for lines that had changed within a single file.  I can't find the functionality right now, although there's a setting for 'Unified Diff Viewer'.  Anyway, what I would ideally like is a report that concatenates together the unified diff results for each file, separated by the filename and a few line-breaks.  I may add a brief example to my question.  Thanks.

Comment: "Unified" is the name of a [diff format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format), not a method for creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click your working copy.
2. TortoiseSVN -> Create Patch
3. Select your files
4. Click OK
5. Save the file when prompted

This will create a [Unified Diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) file which describes all the uncommitted changes.

You can also do this at the command line. `svn diff > myfile.diff`

Comment: Thanks @alroc, I'll try that out, but it won't be for a little over a week because I'm finishing shortly and then having a week off.  It sounds like roughly what I'm after though.

Comment: That looks like precisely what I wanted.  Thank you.